# GWT for cycle is not cycling

Tags: java, json, gwt, for-loop

I am developing a GWT application and I have that method:

```
    private static List<Ticket> getTicketsFromJSON(String ticketsJSONString) {
    JSONValue ticketsArrayValue = JSONParser.parseLenient(ticketsJSONString);
    JSONArray ticketsArray = ticketsArrayValue.isArray();
    List<Ticket> ticketsList = new LinkedList<Ticket>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ticketsArray.size(); i++) {

        JSONObject ticketJSON = ticketsArray.get(i).isObject();
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket((int)ticketJSON.get("id").isNumber().doubleValue(), 
                ticketJSON.get("name").isString().stringValue(),
                ticketJSON.get("description").isString().stringValue(),
                (int)ticketJSON.get("complexity").isNumber().doubleValue(),
                (int)ticketJSON.get("priority").isNumber().doubleValue(),
                (long)ticketJSON.get("started").isNumber().doubleValue(),
                (long)ticketJSON.get("finished").isNumber().doubleValue(),
                (long)ticketJSON.get("timespent").isNumber().doubleValue());
        ticketsList.add(ticket);
    }
    Window.alert("Out of the cicle");
    return ticketsList;
}
```

It seems that I enter the cycle but after the creation of the Ticket object nothing is happening. May be the object isn't even initialising. Here is the Ticket class:

```
    package org.kanbanizer.client.beans;

public class Ticket {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int complexity;
    private int priority;
    private long started;
    private long finished;
    private long timespent;

    public Ticket() {
    }

    public Ticket(int id, String name, String description, int complexity,
            int priority, long started, long finished, long timespent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.complexity = complexity;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.started = started;
        this.finished = finished;
        this.timespent = timespent;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getComplexity() {
        return complexity;
    }

    public void setComplexity(int complexity) {
        this.complexity = complexity;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public long getStarted() {
        return started;
    }

    public void setStarted(long started) {
        this.started = started;
    }

    public long getFinished() {
        return finished;
    }

    public void setFinished(long finished) {
        this.finished = finished;
    }

    public long getTimespent() {
        return timespent;
    }

    public void setTimespent(long timespent) {
        this.timespent = timespent;
    }

}
```

I tried to use and Integer.parseInt to get the value but the result was the same. The string that is the argument of the method isn't empty. If someone knows why isn't it working please tell me.

Comment: you should also post an example of the JSON data this is reading, eg the contents of `ticketsJSONString`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your code is crashing on one your JSON get values, eg `(int)ticketJSON.get("complexity").isNumber()`

What happens if those values are null or missing?  Your code will crash with an null pointer exception - NPE.

Put in some lines to check for NPEs.

In general though, you might consider using JavaSsript Overlay Types for this kind of thing.  You can just create an overlay for the ticket instead of copying each value:  http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.ca/2008/08/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-2.html

Comment: Using overlay types is the way better solution than this extremly complex JSON parsing.... I used them often and they work great!

Comment: It's all good, but there are no null values, and the logic is saying that the code should work fine, but it isn't, in fact, it doesn't even finishes a single loop...

Comment: yes, it is probably crashing somewhere.  either step through it with Eclipse or break the code apart and put in println or Window.alert messages and see what line it dies on.